# PHPexcel with displaying proper look

Tags: php, html, excel, phpexcel

I have a problem with merging cells and borders. This is my EXCEL FILE or "text.xls"

I need to display it like this:

[image: this is my EXCEL FILE or "text.xlsx"]

I mean it shows the same even if I edit the excel file. It's exactly the same when the excel file save it as HTML.

This is the output when i try to excecute my program:

[image]

I can do it manualy but the problem is what if i want to change the excel file?
It will totally ruin everything.

I need it to automatically change it without changing the code, only in the Excel file.

This is the part of my project.

This is my code:

```
<?php
    require_once "Classes/PHPExcel.php";

    $tmpfname = "text.xls";
    $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
    $excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);
    $worksheet = $excelObj->getSheet(0);
    $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();

    echo "<table>";
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
         echo "<tr>
         <td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "
         </td>
         <td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('B'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "
         </td>
         <td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('C'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "
         </td>
         <td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('D'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "
         </td>
         <td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('E'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "
         </td>
         <td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('F'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "
         </td>
         <td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('G'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "
         </td>
         <td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('H'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "
         </td>
         <tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";    
?>
```

Comment: Why not let PHPExcel's HTML Write generate the page?

Comment: what do you mean ?
and how ?

Comment: `$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excelObj, 'HTML');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objWriter->save('php://output');`

Comment: thank you for the answer but.. .
can you be more precise how do i do it ?

Comment: Replace every line of code in your script after the line that reads `$excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);` with the three lines that I listed in my previous comment

Comment: What do you mean `display the CSS`... is it generating correct html?

Comment: i fix it by creating a new one ..Excel file 
and refresh it .. with the same code .. 
but the my first try .. 

the table display the looks like what i mentioned above 
and ... display also the `<style>` part 
it display 
html{}
tabble{}

it display like removed `<style>`

Comment: BTW thank you so much for your answer it helps me a LOT :D